# REST API wrapper testing

Tags: c#, rest, nunit, moq

I'm writing wrapper for REST API of a service. In my wrapper I have quite simple method:

```
public List<string> GetAvailableSources()
{
    var request = new RestRequest($"session/{Id}");
    var sessionProto = _client.Execute<SessionPrototype>(request);
    return sessionProto.Data.InstalledSources;
}
```

It's really simple and just sends request to service and returns result. However, unit test for that method is huge:

```
[Test]
public void GetAvailableSources_MustReturnItemsFromResponse()
{
    const long sessionId = 123;

    var clientMock = new Mock<IRestClient>();

    clientMock.Setup(x => x.Execute<SessionPrototype>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
        .Returns(new RestResponse<SessionPrototype>()
        {
            Data = new SessionPrototype
            {
                Id = sessionId,
                InstalledSources = new List<string>
                {
                    "Scanner1",
                    "Scanner2"
                }
            },
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        }).Verifiable();

    var session = new Session(sessionId, clientMock.Object);
    var sources = session.GetAvailableSources();
    Assert.That(sources, Has.Count.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(sources[0], Is.EqualTo("Scanner1"));
    Assert.That(sources[1], Is.EqualTo("Scanner2"));
    clientMock.Verify(
        m => m.Execute<SessionPrototype>(
            It.Is<IRestRequest>(
                r => r.Resource == $"session/{sessionId}" && r.Method == Method.GET)));
}
```

Is there a way for simplifying tests for REST API?

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify entire test class by extracting part responsible for general configuration. Then you can easili split your test into two, first verifying that your `IRestClient` is properly called during the process and second that assures tested method returns result provided by this client. For tests that require specific configuration, like throwing exceptions and so on, I found it a nice way to extract this configuration to separate, private methods and calling them when necessary instead of configuring all the scenarios in the Setup method.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ClientTest
{
    private const long SessionId = 123;
    private Mock<IRestClient> _clientMock;
    private List<string> _expectedSources;
    private Session _session;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _expectedSources = new List<string>
                {
                    "Scanner1",
                    "Scanner2"
                };
        _clientMock = new Mock<IRestClient>();
        _clientMock.Setup(x => x.Execute<SessionPrototype>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
                   .Returns(new RestResponse<SessionPrototype>()
        {
            Data = new SessionPrototype
            {
                Id = SessionId,
                InstalledSources = _expectedSources
            },
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        }).Verifiable();

        _session = new Session(SessionId, _clientMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetAvailableSources_MustCallTheClientUsingProperRequest()
    {
        _clientMock.Verify(
            m => m.Execute<SessionPrototype>(
                It.Is<IRestRequest>(
                r => r.Resource == $"session/{SessionId}" && 
                     r.Method == Method.GET)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetAvailableSources_ReturnsSourcesProvidedByClient()
    {
        var sources = _session.GetAvailableSources();

        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(_expectedSources, sources);
    }
}
```